# Android Instrumentation Test fail on Travis CI AVD but work on local emulator

Tags: android, travis-ci, instrumentation, android-virtual-device

If i run instrumentation tests on my local emulator they run 10 out of 10 times perfectly but when I try to run the same tests on an AVD in Travis CI, I randomly get

`FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent {  } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was xxxxxxx and now the last time the queue went idle was: xxxxxxxxx. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.`

I have tried removing all progress bars and everything but still its an issue that is only happening randomly and on Travis. 
My travis.yml looks like this:

```
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-19
    - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
  before_script:
      - android list targets
      - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
      - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -no-boot-anim &
      - android-wait-for-emulator
      - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
    script:
      - ./gradlew jacocoTestReport assembleAndroidTest connectedCheck zipalignRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `android-wait-for-emulator` script, please [remove](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/blob/acib/scripts/acib#L40) the `-no-boot-anim` option it [depends on](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/blob/acib/scripts/acib#L127) to detect when emulator is ready.

Alternatively, replace the `android-wait-for-emulator` script by a fixed [sleep time](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/blob/acib-fixes/scripts/acib#L126) like this:

```
  - sleep 300
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

You need to choose the sleep time based on each API boot duration.